# Error: Open Files From my project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i need to make program which can the user select his file path from his computer and then click on start button to OPen... and when he close the program and return open it again. can Direct open his program that he select without click on select file path again... but i get thes error
[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvb4h.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nS2E.png)

My Codes:..

Select Button

If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If

Open Button:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```

i add OpenFileDialoge.

What can i do to make the user can open and close the program several Time and save the path file without select it again...

Comment: Look at `My.Settings` The question doesnt quite seem to fit the title

Comment: what did You mean?.. My.settings.save is to save file path in textbox1 i thought that when i make this i can open the file Direct from my button.. @Plutonix

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.